# VC++ 2010 SDK for VC++ 2008, 2005 clients

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdk, backwards-compatibility

I want to write SDK using Visual C++ 2010, which can be used by VC++ 2010 clients, and also old VC++ version clients. Let's say, I want to have it compatible for 2005 and 2008 versions. SDK contains several h, lib and dll files. Libraries have exported C++ classes and global functions. Public SDK interface (h-files) doesn't contain any feature that is not supported in previous VC++ versions. Internal SDK implementation may contain such features (like Lambda expressions, rvalue references etc.).

Some public SDK methods have callback interface parameters. Callback interfaces are defined in my h-files, implemented in the client code and passed to my methods. Can this be a problem?

I made several small tests and found that it works. Does anyone know any problem with using VC++ 2010 SDK by C++ clients, written in old VC++ versions?

Comment: There might be run-time library compatibility issues. It's a guess, but a valid one, I think... In fact, it's not a guess: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @AzzA - good point. My SDK doesn't pass such objects in its interface. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key principles:

- You cannot expose any objects from the standard C++ library (std::string etc), their layout is not compatible
- You cannot use exceptions, SEH is okay
- You cannot return any pointers that require the client code to release the pointed-to resource
- You should build with /MT so the client doesn't have a headache digging up the required CRT version
- You are generally okay with object layout between 2003 through 2010 as long as you can ensure it is not affected by compiler settings other than /Zp.  Virtual inheritance has been troublesome.  Verify that sizeof yields the same size regardless of the selected configuration.

COM is a good way to ensure maximum compatibility.

Comment: SDK uses exceptions both internally, and as part of SDK interface. There is my own exported exception class (not derived from std::exception), which is thrown by another exported classes methods. So, this may fail?

Comment: Another question: is this problem the same, as, for example, compatibility between SDK written in VC++ 2005, and VC++ 2010 client? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use exceptions.  The only safe way is when the code that throws and the code that catches lives in the same module.  Clearly not the case in an API.  The allocator is the problem, can't safely destroy the exception object.  You'll have to use SEH (unpractical) or error codes, like HRESULT.  And yes, a safe API works just as well in VS2010 when you built it with VS2005.

Comment: So, I can use exceptions internally, but they should not be a part of the public interface. I can live with this, replacing external exceptions with kind of "return code + GetLastErrorInfo" model. Thanks.

Comment: One more (hopefully last) question. I edited my post, adding new information about callback interfaces. Can you comment this, please?

Comment: It was meant to be a complete list :(  Callbacks are not a problem as long as their arguments follow the same rules.  Just declare the calling convention explicitly to avoid accidents.  The CALLBACK macro is boilerplate.

Comment: CALLBACK is not applicable in this context, since I am using callback interfaces, and not functions, is it OK?

Comment: Regarding /MT restriction - is it critical? What kind of headache it creates for a client, if I use default /MD option? Can client finally solve this (even having some headache...) ?

Comment: Using /MD is admitting that your API is not safe.  There's just no point in avoiding /MT if it is really safe.  Use it right away so you'll get slapped hard asap when you get it wrong.